# ticks start douplicating on zooming d3js

Tags: javascript, graph, charts, d3.js

I implemented zoom in a d3 line chart.Working fine.
But after zooming at some level.The ticks in y axis started to come in decimal number like ( 3.400000001) then I added the code

```
.tickFormat(d3.format(",.0f"))
```

Then the problem was solved the number became whole number.
But now another problem arises that on zooming on some level the same number started to repeat on y-axis.
How to solve that problem

Or tell me a way to limit the ticks in y-axis to two decimal places.

This is my code for Yaxis

```
var yAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(y).tickFormat(d3.format(",.0f")).ticks(10).orient("left");
```

Comment: Have you tried `.tickFormat(d3.format(",.2f"))`?

Answer (score 1):

> Try like this :

```
var yAxis = d3.svg.axis().orient("left").scale(y).ticks(10, d3.format(",d")).tickSubdivide(4).tickSize(6, 3, 0);
```